# How to converse an array of n-column labels to 1-column?

Tags: python, numpy

this  is a label array that I use in my classification model:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

But I'd like to reverse it to one column, so it will look like this:

```
  array([[0],
   [1],
   [2]], dtype=uint8)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

```
np.argmax(arr, axis=1).reshape(arr.shape[0], 1).astype(np.int8)

# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2]], dtype=int8)
```

If you want to take always the position of the `ones`:

```
np.argmax(arr==1, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one valid value in your original array per row (as in your example) and, assuming you called that array `a` you could use `numpy's where()` function, like `np.where(a)` and get the second array that is returned. E.g. `np.where(a)[1]`.

This only works if the values that you want to omit are `0` or `False`.

That second array contains the positions where the values in the columns evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]])

def pos(lis):
    return np.where(lis == 1)[0]

posvec = np.apply_along_axis(pos, 1, arr)
```

Comment: This answer may be correct, but it will be clearer if you add it to the explanation about it.

Comment: simply, here the code runs on each row of the 2D-array and find the index of number 1 first appears in that row. Specialty is that run that complete operation in a vectorized manner; using `np.apply_along_axis` function.